# Python one-liner for stdin direct to zlib.compress

Tags: python

I am trying to write a one-line to take a file as stdin and compress then base64, but I got the error bellow:

```
python -c "import sys,base64,zlib; print(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(sys.stdin.readlines())).decode())" < filename.txt
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Comment: stdin must be configured in binary mode. Are you using windows? Plus don't use readlines use read.

Comment: `python -c "import sys,base64,zlib; print(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(sys.stdin.read())).decode())" < filename.txt`

Comment: I am using WSL2/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns a `list` of lines. You need just `os.read()` on the standard input descriptor, and use unbuffered io, because `sys.stdin.read()` returns strings, not bytes (tested on windows).

```
python -u -c "import os,base64,zlib; print(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(os.read(0,1<<62))).decode())" < webex.exe
```

Hack is to pass a huge value to `read` if you don't use a loop so you're pretty sure your file will be smaller than this.

Comment: No luck. Even with the -u flag. The same error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'